# enable production mode in angular 2

Tags: angular, production-environment

I have been creating web application using Angular 2 and Firebase,
I want to enable production mode.

main.ts

```
if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}
```

environment.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: true
};
```

environment.prod.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: true
};
```

Then I'm tried ng build -prod; ng serve ,but still not working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you use angular-cli?

Comment: So, what have you tried? All you need is ng build --prod.

Comment: I'm using angular-cli, I have tried ng build -prod; ng serve, but not working

Comment: Use ng build if you want to build the artefacts. Use ng serve if you want to server them from the cli dev server. Using them one after another doesn't serve any purpose.

Answer (score 12):

`ng build --prod` will create build artifacts in the `/dist` folder - you have to put those files on a different web server *(i.e. you don't use ng serve after that)*.

If you just want to run your app using `ng serve` but using production mode, 
then use:

```
ng serve --prod
```

**Edit**

I don't seem to be doing a good job of explaining this. Your request is to "enable production mode". You have two ways of doing that, depending on what you're trying to do.

If you want to use the angular-cli development server to run your app in production mode as a means of testing to see if production mode works properly, then use:

```
ng serve --prod
```

If, however, you are ready to deploy your app to a production web server, then it's a two step process:

1. generate the production-ready version of your app using: `ng build --prod`
2. copy the output of the `/dist` folder onto your production web server

Note that I don't do both - i use either `ng build` or `ng serve` , depending on what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: /dist disappeared after run ng serve --prod

Comment: /dist is always removed whenever you `ng serve`.

Comment: how I can put files in the folder /dist on a different web server, because when I run ng build --prod then ng serve --prod it still not working

Answer (score 9):

`ng serve --prod` didn't worked for me.

This worked btw

```
ng serve --configuration=production
```

it creates a test production server which works same as it works on the deployed one. I tried this testing with environment.js (all other solutions didn't worked for me)

You can follow [this](https://blog.angularindepth.com/becoming-an-angular-environmentalist-45a48f7c20d8) (Becoming an Angular Environmentalist) article to learn more about Angular environments

Comment: ng serve --prod seems to be deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

You should try again with `ng run build --prod` or `npm run build`
as for me, in my package.json file, I setting script like that

```
"scripts":{
 "ng": "ng",
 "publish": "ng build --prod",
 "start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200",
 "hmr": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200 4201 --hmr -e=hmr",
 "test": "ng test",
 "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
 "e2e": "protractor"},..
```

and then so, when I want to build(publish) my angular project, I used `npm run publish` command.
If you want to change `"build"` instead of `"publish"`, you must use like `"npm run build"`
It will OK.

Answer (score 0):

I have observed this in angular-cli `1.0.0-beta.28.3`. The `dist` disappears on `ng-serve`. If you want to keep the build, try `ng build --output-path=last-build/` and have a look at [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4366).

But the point is you don't need to do a `ng serve --prod` after you have created the `build`. As @snorkpete is saying, please copy the `dist` folder after creating the build to your web server. And your web server will take care of running the app. `Remeber, you will have to create a virtual host for this`. But if you just want to run it on your local machine and want the live `webpack`, Just do `ng serve --prod`, a live `webpack` has nothing to do with the `dist` you have.

Answer (score -1):

For enabling your angular2 app to production mode:

open your angular appfolder and open `main.ts` and in `main.ts` there will be

```
import {environment} './environment/environment'
```

Hust add .prod in the last environment written:

```
import {environment} './environment/environment.prod'
```